# How does video resolution depend on quality qualifier e.g. 720p, 1080p or another?

Tags: video-streaming, screen, standards, video-processing

I assume that 720p means 1280x720 resolution and so on. Am I right? I know that they can be specified independently, but I want to know if there are some standards.

Answer (score 1):

There are many (many) standards, PAL, NTSC, 720, 1080i/p, 4k.  See; [Wikipedia's display resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution) page for all the specifics.  If you are creating video for US TVs 720x1280 and 1080x1920 are the most popular HD resolutions.  It gets more complicated however when you start talking about video that is not 16x9 ratio, in that case typically you keep the largest resolution constant (720x960 for 4x3 content, 544x1280 for 2.35:1 content, etc).